# VirtualBox isn't enabling video acceleration

Tags: virtualbox, 3d, hardware-acceleration

I'm using ubuntu 14.04

In virtual box I enable 2d and 3d acceleration as well as CPU acceleration. I did it after installation but I don't believe it would matter. I installed windows 7 and did the Windows Experience Index. When windows runs natively I get a 6.4, 6.4. In VMWare on windows I get 5.6, 5.2. In VirtualBox I got 1.0 which is the lowest score

I ran `glxinfo | grep render` and got the below so it appears to have some video acceleration. But it doesn't appear to be working in the virtual machine. I'm running Ubuntu from a USB stick on the same machine.

```
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,  OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Desktop 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp,
```

Comment: Did you install the guest additions on the guest OS?

Comment: @Takkat: I didn't. I had no idea there was something like that. It didn't work at first but after I checked off experimental directX it worked like I hoped.